# Uploading Video in php not working

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I want to upload video in php this is my code

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))

    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

      {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

        if (file_exists("store/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
          {
          echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          "store/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          echo "Stored in: " . "store/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
          }
        }
      }

      else
      {
        echo "Invalid file";
      }
}     
?>
```

HTML CODE is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file"><span>Filename:</span></label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

when I upload .mp4 file it showing the message :
***Invalid file***

Give me solution plz

Comment: did you check if `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` does have the expected value (`video/mp4`) and the size didn't exceed the limit(20kb isn't much for a video)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my final code that is working I have change my php code like this

```
<?php


$target_dir = "store/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "mp3" && $imageFileType != "m4v" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

?>
```

With this I can upload mp3 and Mp4 files.
I have change the validation for file formate and size of file in the code...

Comment: Please don't add random tag formatting to words in tag wikis, unless they actually refer to the tag itself. As well, tag wiki exceprts do not support any formatting in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

```
Change it:
($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)

To:
($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Because your code:**

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

is returning only extension after dot. e.g. `mp4`, `mp3`

And you expect it to be:

`video/mp4` OR `audio/mp3`

I think you need [mime type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) of the file.

```
mime_content_type($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

**Solution:**

*Change*

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

*To*

```
$extension = mime_content_type($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

EDIT:

*Change*:

```
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))
```

*To*:

```
if (in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mime_content_type()

Comment: Try $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);echo finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES["file"]["name"])

Comment: I just uncomment the extension=php_fileinfo.dll in php.ini and restart apache for this fatal error

Comment: Now showing warning: mime_content_type(Not Afraid.m4v): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

Comment: Please provide full path, not just name.